# GradCam Implementation in TFJS

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm trying to implement GradCam (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02391.pdf) in tfjs, based on the following Keras Tutorial (http://www.hackevolve.com/where-cnn-is-looking-grad-cam/) and a simple image classification demo from tfjs, similar to (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/webcam-transfer-learning/index.js) with a simple dense, fully-connected layer at the end.

However, I'm not able to retrieve the gradients needed for the gradcam computation. I tried different ways to retrieve gradients for the last sequential layer, but did not succeed, as types of tf.LayerVariable from the respective layer is not convertible to the respective type of tf.grads or tf.layerGrads.

Did anybody already succeeded to get the gradients from sequential layer to a tf.function like object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This official example in the tfjs-examples repo should be close to, if not exactly, what you want:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/visualize-convnet/cam.js#L49

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of the ins and outs of the implementation, but I think something along the lines of this: http://jlin.xyz/advis/ is what you're looking for?

Source code is available here: https://github.com/jaxball/advis.js (not mine!)

Comment: Thanks for the hint to CAM, which is quiet similar. However, as I can not add a global average pooling in my network, I need to switch to the more general grad cam, which requires gradient computation (which however does not work in tfjs with my model and code atm).